# C string question

Tags: c

All I simply want to do is a make a record that starts with C or D randomly and has a number along with it 1-10. so a record would be C10. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

/*
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char letter[] = { 'C', 'D' };
    char record[2];
    int r=1;
    while (r < 11)
    {
            char num;
            num = r;
            record = (letter[rand()%2],num);
            r++;
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read a little bit about c-strings (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string). A c-string i s a null-terminated array of char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
record = (letter[rand()%2],num);
```

This is not a legal opporation... try this:

```
record[0] = letter[rand()%2];
record[1] = num;
```

Comment: `record[1] = num;` wont work as they expect.  you'd need to `snprintf` it.

Comment: This still leaves a invalid c-string. record is only 2 bytes long and it would need a '\0' to terminate.

Comment: That assumes the OP wants a valid c-string (presumably he does and does not actually know it). This answer does however fix the immediate problem with the cited line. There are other issues the OP does not seem to be aware of however.

Answer (score 3):

For one obvious point, "C10" requires 4 characters, assuming you want it as a normal C string (3 in the string + 1 NUL terminator) but you've only made room for 2.

At least assuming you want your 1-10 as text characters, you'd typically want to do something like:

```
sprintf(record, "%c%d", letter[rand()%2], num);
```

Not that it matters a lot, but you seem to be including a *lot* of unnecessary headers for what you're doing.

Comment: @Node: `snprintf` certainly *can* be useful at times, but here it doesn't really add anything useful. The only real reason to use it is to maintain it as a good habit.

Comment: I have tried this way and it still prints out a bunch of values attached. This is just a portion of a larger project OI am working on.

Comment: @Ancide: `snprintf` takes the length of your buffer as an argument, and returns the number of characters that _would_ have been written if the buffer was large enough.  If its smaller than your buffer, happy days.  If its not, you can handle the error.  You _could_ even call `snprintf` passing it a `NULL` buffer and `0` length, to find out how much space you need to `malloc` to fit the whole c-string.

Comment: @Node Thanks for the explanation! I have loads of more questions. But I'll read up on it instead of starting a discussion here :)

Answer (score 2):

You want the characters '0'-'9' popping up, but you are assigning the character r a numerical value between 0 and 10. Check out the [table of ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/).

I'd try it like this:

```
char record[4];
for (unsigned r = 0; r <= 10; ++r) {
   snprintf(record, sizeof(record), "%c%d", letter[rand() % 2], r);
}
```

Comment: +1 - but would be better if you pass `sizeof(record)` instead of `4`.